# BundleContext is no longer valid

Tags: osgi-bundle

I am having a Java web application which runs in an OSGi container. I have deployed my application on a  Tomcat server. When I restart my server sometimes I am randomly getting mutiple instaces of error "**BundleContext is no longer valid**" and hence I am unable to deploy the application. It doesn't happen all the time when we restart our application server but happens sometimes only. The only solution we found is just to restart the server. Following is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyServiceManager] : Adding
OSGi service dependency for importer [&simplyticOsgiSaeAdapter] matching OSGi filter [(objectClass=c
om.moodysanalytics.sae.simplytic.adapter.SimplyticSaeAdapter)]
[org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean] : Creating a single
service proxy ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (
1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'dataSource
' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: **BundleContext is no longer valid**
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api[org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDele
gate] : No XML 'id' specified - using 'templateElement' as bean name and [] as aliases
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAcce
ssor.java:102)
[org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] : FactoryBean threw exception
 from getObjectType, despite the contract saying that it should return null if the type of its objec
```

Comment: I ran the ss command on the osgi console and found that all the bundles are either in active or resolved state .